# How to indent content of region with C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I would really like to have VS2008 automatically indent the contents of a region. A sample would probably be best.

What is does now:

```
#region [ Fields ]
public int Count;
public int Total;
#endregion
```

What I'd like is:

```
#region [ Fields ]
    public int Count;
    public int Total;
#endregion
```

How can I get VS to do this?

EDIT: 
For what its worth, VS **does** do this in VB.NET.

Comment: might be worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476550/c-any-standard-way-to-divide-a-class-into-regions/1476582#1476582

Comment: Interesting comments and the Coding Horror blog was interesting. The comment that most interested me was the analogy with a surgeon. I.e. the patient is covered except where the surgeon will be working. That's how my mind works best, focus on the issue at hand. Thanks for the different point of view though!

Comment: Typical C# programmer comments in this linked SO article!  Even if you don't like regions (and I do, and miss the auto-indenting VB gave me), it's still a valid question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box? You can't.

Comment: Any addin/tools that would do this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I don't use regions! I just checked ReSharper options, but couldn't see anything.

Answer (score 6):

This macro should work, for the most part:

```
Public Sub IndentRegions()
    'Assume that the document has been smart formatted
    Dim TS As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
    TS.SelectAll()
    Dim lines As String() = TS.Text.Split(vbNewLine)

    Dim level As Integer = 0

    TS.StartOfDocument()

    While Not TS.ActivePoint.AtEndOfDocument

        If lines(TS.ActivePoint.Line - 1).Trim().StartsWith("#endregion") Then
            level = level - 1
        End If

        For i = 1 To level
            TS.Indent()
        Next

        If lines(TS.ActivePoint.Line - 1).Trim().StartsWith("#region") Then
            level = level + 1
        End If

        TS.LineDown()
        TS.StartOfLine()
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the macro. This does do what is suggested (assuming you actually make a selection...DOH!): it indents the lines under a region. However, as soon as I use Ctl+K+D to reformat, the work is undone!  So, for now, I'm just living with it.

Comment: You could write a macro that performs the smart format and then runs indent regions. I don't know if you could re-map Ctrl+K D to the macro (I'm sure you could map another key sequence, though).

Answer (score 4):

Change the background color to another color other than the main page background (I used silver on top of white) and it will give it that indented feel that you are looking for.

`Options` > `Environment` > `Fonts and Colors` > Display Items: `Preprocessor Keyword` and then change the `item background` dropdown.

Comment: i love this answer. there are indents and indents :)

Comment: This works well, not what was asked but does the trick of visually highlighting the regions.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the only way to simulate this is to use braces "{" and "}" inside regions, delimiting your code block. Unfortunatelly this only works inside Functions and Methods codes, hence this will not work for your example. In some cases, delimiting code blocks could be incompatible and require adjustments according with your code logic.

```
function Test(){

    #region Example
    {
        your code
    }
    #end region

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tools
Options
Text Editor
C#
Tabs
Indent
Smart Ident

Comment: This didn't actually indent the contents of a region (at least for me).